# Change from Activity to AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I changed from Activity to AppCompatActivity.

Added this to gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0"
}
```

but my app is crashing. The reason for the change is that I want to edit my actionbar. For example: to add a logo etc.

Logcat:

```
    02-22 15:02:22.780 2065-2065/com.example.hansbaum.calculator I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-22 15:02:22.880 2065-2065/com.example.hansbaum.calculator D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-22 15:02:22.880 2065-2065/com.example.hansbaum.calculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: com.example.hansbaum.calculator, PID: 2065
                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hansbaum.calculator/com.example.hansbaum.calculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                            at com.example.hansbaum.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
02-22 15:02:53.210 2065-2065/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2065 SIG: 9
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hansbaum.calculator" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please, post logcat crash here

Comment: "my app is crashing" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: ok the logcat is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your manifest file you need to use AppCompat theme for you activity.
For example:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Add theme for your activity in manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Also in your activity code you should now use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of  `getActionBar()`

In your styles.xml replace  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` by  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">` and in your manifest replace both `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` by `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: can you please add your manifest file here

Comment: I did. Thanks for helping !

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Crash again. updated logcat

Comment: ok know the app is starting but it lost all the materiel design features like the colors.

Comment: have updated my answer again

Comment: I did. the App is starting now, but there isn't the material theme.

Comment: Your original question was about crash :) What do you mean "there isn't the material theme"? What are you expecting?

Comment: Before I switched to AppCombatActivity I used the Material Colors in my style.xml. Now with the AppCombatActivity the app hasn't the colors.

Comment: This happened because now you are using new theme for activity, and this theme is not from your styles. now you need to set parent theme @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light for you customized theme in styles.xml. then you need to set this theme (your custom theme from styles with new parent) to your activity in manifest.

Comment: this is that i did: http://pastebin.com/PVP26uMk

Comment: updated my answer with new tips

Comment: ok the textview edittexts and buttons are all right but the color of the actionbar is not right.

Comment: try to remove "android:" from your "<item name="android:colorPrimary">" and "<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">". it should be just "<item name="colorPrimary">" and <item name="colorPrimaryDark">.

Comment: omg you are awesome!

Comment: you can mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: You also can add google android material "com.google.android.material:material" then still possible to use material theme because their themes are descendents of `Theme.AppCompat` https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/31af945caa6216237441e5888c2714464075b2d7/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/res/values/themes_base_bridge.xml#L28